# how to enable and disable button based on user role?

Tags: asp.net, button, roles

I have a role called 'member' and another 'admin' in Asp.Net website.

I did before, that button should be visible or not and i am successful in that,but,i am not able to get the proper code(aspx.cs) to disable the button so that it may be in view but not at all accessible.

```
<asp:Button ID="Button4" runat="server" PostBackUrl="~/report.aspx" 
   Text="print in report format" Width="173px" 
   Enabled='<%# HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Admin") %>' />
```

i want that whenever a member login then button "report" should be disabled for him.

Comment: why i can't answer this question , there is a problem with me or the question :/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to set the `Button.Enabled` property value to according to the `HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("admin")` function returned value.

Either in html:

```
<Button ... Enabled='<%# HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Admin") %>' ... >
```

Or in code behind:

```
Button.Enabled = HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Admin");
```

Comment: thanks it's done.I have no words to explain how much this site boosts my confidence.Thanks once again

Answer (score 6):

```
if (HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("member"))
{
  //enable/disable here
}
```

Comment: +1: This should really be done in the code behind. It can be done in the html side, but there's really no point to do it that way. It's even less readable/maintainable IMO.

Answer (score 3):

In the Page_Load after checking for the role you may be able to set the IsEnabled for the Button to be False.

e.g. buttonLogin.Enabled = (IsUserInRole(Admin));

Answer (score 2):

Either I'm missing something or the solution is simply:

```
button.Enabled = false;
```

Comment: button should be enabled to admin not member.how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you are using an ASP.NET button control - if you are then you need to set the `Visible` and `Enabled` button properties to `false`

Comment: button should be enabled to admin not member.how to do that?

Answer (score 1):

The primary problem you have here is the hash mark: `<%#` is used to identify a binding. Unless you're calling this in a gridview or a formview or something, this will not work. I would recommend setting it in the code behind as suggested by @Muhammad Akhtar, but if you're hell bent for leather on using the html side it should probably be:

```
Enabled='<%= HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Admin").ToString() %>'
```