# ListView disable Insert and Edit buttons based on role

Tags: asp.net

I've a requirement to disable edit/create buttons in ListView.Could anyone please show me how to enable or disable  Edit/Create buttons in ListView from code behind, please.

Not sure if this is possible.

```
<InsertItemTemplate>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <asp:Button ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CommandName="Insert" 
                Text="Insert" CssClass="button" 
                ValidationGroup="InsertValidation" CausesValidation="true" />
            <asp:Button ID="CancelButton" runat="server" CommandName="Cancel" 
                Text="Clear" CssClass="button" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</InsertItemTemplate>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [RolePrincipal.IsInRole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprincipal.isinrole.aspx).

The code should be similiar to the following:

```
void listView_ItemDataBound(...)
{
    Button targetButton = (Button) e.Item.FindControl("TargetButtonName");

    targetButton.Enabled = User.IsInRole("Administrators");
}
```

---

Refer to [how to enable and disable button based on user role?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992172/how-to-enable-and-disable-button-based-on-user-role/5993873#5993873)

Comment: Thank you @Akram for all your help. If I knew you in-person I would have taken you for free coffee. Your time is much appreciated.

Comment: @Akram, I tried Button targetInsertButton = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("InsertButton");
            targetInsertButton.Enabled = false;   It's giving Object Reference not set error. However EditButton works fine.

Comment: @flybyte: If you posted your html markup, I will be able to help you with that ...

Comment: not sure what you meant. I tried this and not working :Button targetInsertButton = (Button)e.Item.FindControl("InsertButton");
            targetInsertButton.Enabled = false;

Comment: @flybyte: Insert button resides in the insert item .. you have to check the item type before trying to find the insert button ..

Comment: @@flybyte: Refer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5992172/how-to-enable-and-disable-button-based-on-user-role/5993873#5993873

Comment: Thanks but its not going to work for me as my role is based on custom database i.e. Teamleader, supervisor etc.

Comment: @flybyte: It is hard to tell what's going on on your code .. The provided info must help you figure it out. You still need to make some effort. Try debugging a little ...